# None controlled parameters routing

Tags: angular

I have an application that is redirected to a sts provider. After login user is redirected back to my application, with an id_token parameter. I tried following:

```
{path:'dashboard/:id_token',component: DashboardComponent,canActivate: [AdalGuard]}
```

But I still get error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'id_token' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'id_token'

How do you configure this?

Comment: What is complete return URL?

Comment: http://localhost:4200/authcallback#id_token=xxxxxx&state=xxx&session_state=xx

Comment: your route will only work when URL will be something like this `dashboard/xxxx`